# How can I play audio files from firebase in flutter?

Tags: firebase, audio, dart, flutter

I want to make an audiobooks app that contains many audio files with high quality, so to make the app size smaller, so I uploaded the audios in firebase, but I don't know what to do to play it from my flutter app.

Comment: Please add more details to your question. what is the problem? have you searched for examples of audio playing apps? currently, whoever wants to answer your question should write a full app and put it here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use AudioPlayer plugin https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/audioplayer

First get the URL(say kURL) of the uploaded audio file.

Then pass it to this method provided by plugin

```
 audioPlayer.play(kUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

An good alternative might be audioplayers, if you need it for games

```
https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers
```

simply call the constructor:

```
AudioPlayer audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer(mode: PlayerMode.LOW_LATENCY);

play() async {
    int result = await audioPlayer.play(url);
    if (result == 1) {
      // success
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is a good plugin. But the loading when use firebase urls with this plugin was very slow. I'm testing https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio with aws s3 bucket urls and it also supports audio streaming easily.